# Neo4j count() returning incorrect value

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following query:

```
MATCH (ld:Lead{id:'50309649-f892-4819-aa31-e34f3844aecd'})-[:IS_IN]->(pc:PostCode)<-[:COVERS]-(advisor:User{userType:30, isApproved:true, isUnavailable:false})-[:HAS]->(q:Qualification)<-[:SUPPORTED_BY]-(advType:AdviceType)<-[:REQUIRES]-(ld)
WHERE NOT (ld)-[:IS_ALLOCATED_TO]->(advisor)

OPTIONAL MATCH (ldExisting:Lead)-[rAllocated:IS_ALLOCATED_TO]->(advisor) WHERE rAllocated.status = 0 OR rAllocated.status = 10

return advisor, COUNT(ldExisting) as existingCount
```

It returns a list of "advisors" and is meant to also return a count of the number of existing "IS_ALLOCATED_TO" relationships that each advisor already has.

In my database I have created ONE "IS_ALLOCATED_TO" relationship.  So in this instance it SHOULD be returning a count of 1 for the affected advisor.  However, it's returning a value of 3.

Any thoughts on this most welcome.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that MATCHes will find all matching patterns in the graph. Most likely what's happening is your initial MATCH is finding multiple matches that involve the same `advisor` node, so you will have multiple rows where `advisor` refers to the same node. Given the counts you've said exist in your graph, I'm guessing the same `advisor` node value is the same on 3 separate rows, before your OPTIONAL MATCH executes (you can check that by doing a `RETURN advisor` before your OPTIONAL MATCH and commenting out the rest).

Then your OPTIONAL MATCH executes, and (like all Cypher operations) it executes on all rows, meaning it's performing the same operation from the same `advisor` node 3 times, traversing the same relationship, matching to the same `ldExisting` node, and counting that same node for those 3 rows, giving you the result of 3.

To fix this, you need to ensure you're working with DISTINCT nodes for `advisor`, so you won't have multiple rows with the same node, like so:

```
MATCH (ld:Lead{id:'50309649-f892-4819-aa31-e34f3844aecd'})-[:IS_IN]->(pc:PostCode)<-[:COVERS]-(advisor:User{userType:30, isApproved:true, isUnavailable:false})-[:HAS]->(q:Qualification)<-[:SUPPORTED_BY]-(advType:AdviceType)<-[:REQUIRES]-(ld)
WHERE NOT (ld)-[:IS_ALLOCATED_TO]->(advisor)
WITH DISTINCT advisor
...
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you.  That makes complete sense.  Much appreciated!  I just tried this and it works perfectly.